# When I lock my laptop, the screen keeps Turing on and off repeatedly

Tags: display, lock

When I lock my laptop and wait the screen to turn off, then after like 7 seconds it turns on, and it keeps doing that repeatedly, I noticed that it only happens when I leave something downloading, why it is happening? Please help me

Comment: Perhaps it's an on/off Turing machine?

Comment: The screen does not turn off because you lock the computer. It waits until the power setting turns it off. Have you set the power setting to a time which is too short?